# print problem for invisible data

Tags: jquery, css, printing

I have used onclick function. after click a button show data. but intially data has hidden using inline css property display:none. i want to print intially hidden data that are not shown in browser

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. And can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define a CSS with media type print where the data isn't hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another CSS that shows the hidden parts with `media="print"`.